# Exception disposing memoryMappedFile in linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I'm getting an exception calling dispose on a MemoryMappedFile but only in linux.  The code is .net core 2.1 When I run the code in windows it's working fine, it's just in linux that it breaks.

```
Input/output error
System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedView.Flush(UIntPtr capacity)
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedViewAccessor.Flush()
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedViewAccessor.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
```

The code is doing nothing special in the dispose

```
if (disposing)
{
     if (MyMemoryMappedViewAccessor != null)
     {
         if (MyBytePointer != null)
             MyMemoryMappedViewAccessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ReleasePointer();

         MyMemoryMappedViewAccessor.Dispose();
     }

     if (MyMemoryMappedFile != null)
         MyMemoryMappedFile .Dispose();
}
```

Anyone got any good ideas?

Comment: Can you create a minimal example?